# oauth.io server - how to enable auth user info

Tags: oauth.io

I've set up Oauth.io server to point to the endpoint running on my own WordPress install which has the WP-Oauth plugin installed.

However, the "Auth User Info" flag in oauth.io is disabled, and the JS call to either result.me() or result.get("/me") seems to return nothing.

But - the WP-Oauth plugin DOES support /me.

So what is Oauth.io using to determine whether /me is available?

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

All providers in OAuth.io are implemented on Github here: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/tree/master/providers

You can use the `me()` method if the `me.js` file exists in the provider's folder (e.g. `providers/wordpress/me.js`). It's what enable/disable the "Auth user info" flag in OAuth.io.

This `me.js` file describe how to return the unified user data from the provider's API. As wordpress don't have this file, you currently can't use the me() method with this provider. I will take a look to add it soon but if you want to speed up the process, we accept pull request ;)